# Is Interlocked.Exchange<T> the intended Swap method from Microsoft?

Tags: c#, .net

So do we not need to implement our own Swap method? Is Interlocked.Exchange the intended Swap method from Microsoft?

Answer (score 6):

Interlocked.Exchange doesn't swap its arguments. Only the first argument is changed, not the second argument. The "exchange" refers to exchanging a new value for the first argument for its old value.

This makes it a very poor choice for a swap function.

Answer (score 2):

No reason why not, although it's not completely general purpose:

- It's guaranteed to be atomic, i.e. thread-safe; you probably don't need this most of the time.
- Interlocked.Exchange only works on reference types: there are different overloads for int, long, IntPtr, float and double.

Comment: What if you wanna change 2 structs?

Comment: If you want to atomically swap two structs, you use a normal swap routine (i.e. not Interlocked.Exchange) surrounded by lock (...).

Comment: swap(a,b)->t=a,a=b,b=t : 3 transactions. using interlocked swap(a,b)->interlockedExchange(a,interlockedExhcange(b,a));  the problem is not resolved as it is still 2 operations which can be split.

Comment: as Strilanc said, Interlocked.Exchange does *not* perform a swap operation

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer this to your own Swap method.

Interlocked.Exchange provides a way to handle exchanges atomically.  It's basically the managed wrapper for [InterlockedExchangedPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683609(VS.85).aspx).

There are many advantages to using this over your own swap method, at least in threaded situations.  Since this is a single, atomic operation, it is much safer in a threaded application.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it for simple swap operations since it will serialize access to memory, probably invalidate cpu caches and stall the cpu(s). If you need to manage concurrency, there are better ways to do it than swaps in .NET.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what better ways?

Comment: I know Monitor class or lock can handle most of things. Regarding simple swaps... What's wrong with using a temporary? :P

Answer (score 1):

swap(a,b)->t=a,a=b,b=t : 3 transactions which can be split

using interlocked swap(a,b)->interlockedExchange(a,interlockedExhcange(b,a)); 
the problem is not resolved as it is still 2 operations which can be split.

it seems for the moment the best way to get an interlockedSwap is to put a critical section around to ensure the steps don't get split.

Looking at this a different way, if T was a pair< a, b >, you could construct a new pair with the values swapped, and then use interlockedExchange of T - however the actions of building the pair to swap in may suffer data sheering if somebody else is swapping, or already be swapped when you try and do the exchange.  So again you need a critical section around to ensure the steps don't get split.

Comment: Did I miss something? AFAICT @Joan didn't say anything about concurrency or a need for atomicity. Is that implicit in "the intended Swap method"?

Comment: Thats the way I read it - Interlocked functions implying do all this at once. Otherwise I'm not sure the relationship made in the question between interlocked.exchange and swap as it was already noted exchange didn't perform an actual swap.